# Keeping two nodes next to each other when drawing a vis.js network

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I am trying to draw a family tree with vis.js using hierarchical layout. Some nodes represent a husband and wife, which are connected to each other with an edge. I would like such node pairs to be placed next to each other - however vis.js places them apart with other nodes in between.

Is there some way to instruct vis.js to keep two nodes together and draw them next to each other ?

These are the current network options I am using:

```
var tree_options = 
{
    nodes: 
    {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderWidthSelected: 1,
        shape: "box",
        color: 
        {
            border: 'lightgray',
            background: 'white',
            highlight: 
            {
                border: 'lightgray',
                background: 'lightblue'
            },
            hover: 
            {
                border: 'lightgray',
                background: 'lightblue'
            }
        }
    },
    edges: 
    {
        smooth: 
        {
            type: 'cubicBezier',
            forceDirection: 'vertical',
            roundness: 0.5
        },
        color: 'lightgray'
    },
    layout: 
    {
        hierarchical: 
        {
            direction: 'UD',
            nodeSpacing: 150,
            parentCentralization: true,
            sortMethod: 'directed'
        }
    },
    interaction: 
    {
        dragNodes: true
    },
    physics: false
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Given it is a hierarchical network, have you tried setting a value for "level" on each node?

See example: http://visjs.org/examples/network/layout/hierarchicalLayoutUserdefined.html

Comment: Yes, I am setting a level for each node. My problem is that 2 nodes that have the same level and represent husband+wife are not necessarily places next to each other in the graph - in some cases other nodes are placed in between them. My question is whether there is some way to make sure these 2 nodes are "tied" together and shown next to each other. In the example you provided - let's say I would like nodes 1 and 11 to be drawn next to each other.

Comment: The only possibilities I can think of are:

(a) have an edge between the two nodes and specify a short edge length

(b) somehow figure out and set the x,y of those nodes

(c) change the physics

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try to "play" with the various parameters but could not get this to work for now.

Comment: Hey Tulip, were u able to achieve this? I am also stuck at something similar.